# How to query values from database using <= - mysql

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table as below. I want to pick the count based on the number the user types. For instance, if user type 10, the count selected should be 2. That is easy to get. But when user types 20 or 30, i want to pick the count of 10 which is 2 since 20 or 30 is lesser than 40.

With my query below, when user types 60, it selects the count of 10 which is (2).  How can i do this better ?

```
Number   Count

10         2

40         10

60         20
```

**Controller**

```
$count = PriceRate::where('number','<=',$amount)->first();

return $count;
```

Comment: try this     `$count = PriceRate::where('number','<=',$amount)->orderByDesc('number')->limit(1)->first();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 $count = PriceRate::where('number','<=',$amount)->orderByDesc('number')->limit(1)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this code will help you:

```
    $count_array = [];
    $user_type;
    $Rates= PriceRate::all();
        foreach ($Rates as $rate){
            if ($rate->number <= $user_type){
                array_push($count_array,$user);
            }
        }
```

i will explain whats happening

1-you need an array for your counts-$count_array

2-your user type

3-you get all records from your table

4-you loop them and check for every one of them if its number is equal ol less than your user_type you push that record to your count_array

now you have an array with records from your db that their number is less than your user_type

**edit:** if you want to just have the first one, you can break the loop after array_push